# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los datos similares en una tabla?

Tags: r, rstudio, tablas

Necesito hacer una suma de los valores que tengo en una tabla.
contexto: Tengo una tabla bastante extensa (unos 98 mil datos) de la venta de artículos, por mes según el año.

Quiero poder sumar los articulos totales vendidos en un año (o mes) y que me ofrezca una tabla con esos datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es una muestra de los datos, Necesito obtener una tabla que sea:

```
2006  1 
2007  143
2008  15
2009  30
2010  11
```

Answer (score 1):

Para lo que necesitas, solo basta hacer un agrupamiento y luego sumar, con la función `group_by` agrupamos por año o mes, en este caso año y luego sumamos la variable `suma_total`, y usamos el `na.rm = T` en caso de que tengas algún NA entremedio.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(Año = sum(suma_total , na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 0):

Con R base podrías agrupar usando [`aggregate()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate):

```
aggregate(suma_total ~ year + mes, df, sum)
```